# How to create a colour splash effect in iOS using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, colors, swift5

I am looking to create colour splash effect using swift for my iOS app.

I was considering working with UIBezier path to create some random splash shapes so that I could just fill in colour into those paths. Other than that haven't really had any other ideas I could use to achieve this from my search.

Could anyone help me out and point me in right direction for how I could achieve this ?

[image: I am looking to achieve something like this, even if its a bit simpler one]

Answer (score -1):

I would try `Diamond-square` or `Lazy Flood fill` algorithm.

Also take a look at other computer graphics algorithms:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Computer_graphics_algorithms